# Is there any well defined pipes such as stdin, stdout and stderr in a process?

Tags: unix, operating-system, pipe, zos

There is a limit of 8,730 on the number of z/OS UNIX pipes that can be concurrently open in a system. I wrote a program to test if this limit can be reached. I executed this program many times, and the result shows that the creation of the 8727th pipe will fail.

I guess there are 3 well-defined pipes for STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR defined when a UNIX program begins to execute. But I can't find any documents that mention the 'default pipes', so I wonder if my guess is correct?

Comment: Just to clarify - are you talking about streams or pipes? stdin/out/err are file I/O streams; in UNIX, pipes are a special type of file (as noted below by Jim McNamara).

Comment: @zarchasmpgmr: I just talk about pipes.

Comment: Clarify again: are you talking about pipes or file descriptors?  Each pipe consumes two file descriptors, and it is common to have a per-process limit on file descriptors.  Given that stdin,stdout, and stderr will consume 3 of the available fds, perhaps that is what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a system-wide limit, then something else, some other process, has open pipes.

By pipes you mean fifos, which are a special type of file, streams (stdin, stdout, stderr) do not start out life as pipes, but they can be redirected to pipes.  See your man dup() page, and mkfifo() as well.

Comment: Thanks. your answer is clear. But now I encountered a problem on memory with below error infos:                                                         `pipe: EDC5132I Not enough memory. (errno2=0x05970131)
Failed when 8726th pipe was created. Errno: 132`

Comment: As Jim says, somewhere UNIX process(es) is/are running that are consuming three of the pipes. My bet is that system processes are the culprits here.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is correct. They are called [standard streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams).

> In Unix and Unix-like operating systems (and, to some extent, Windows), as well as certain programming language interfaces, the **standard streams are preconnected** input and output channels between a computer program and its environment (typically a text terminal) when it begins execution. The three I/O connections are called standard input (stdin), standard output (stdout) and standard error (stderr).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know there are there default file descriptors: stdin, stdout, stderr when program begins execution. But I am not sure these three I/O connections are pipes.

Comment: They do not start out as pipes, but may be switched over.

Comment: @zarchasmpgmr: Yes. standard streams do not start out as pipe. Currently, the problem is related to memory. BUF_SIZE on zOS is 256(x512Byte). As a result, the test program could consume more than 1G memory (8730x256x512/1024/1024 = 1092.25MB).

Comment: I tested the same program on Linux, the result was OK.  It appears that BUF_SIZE on zOS UNIX is too big, In contrast, BUF_SIZE on Linux is 8, which is much smaller than 256 on zOS UNIX.